# Server sending RST Message

Tags: windows, sockets, tcp, wireshark

I am developing a server, and client messages are sent through a handset. Server and handset are connected through Wifi.

Client sends a HTTP Post message to server, and server is supposed to reply with a 200 ok. It works in most systems, but in some systems, after the server receives the POST Message, it replies with a TCP RST.

Server IP is: 192.168.1.2 and Client IP is : 192.168.1.9. This is the flow when it does not work.

```
|Time     | 192.168.1.9                           |
|         |                   | 192.168.1.2       |                   
|103.313276|         49988 > 5901 [SYN]            |TCP: 49988 > 5901 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=14600 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM=1 TSval=306973 TSecr=0 WS=64
|         |(49988)  ------------------>  (5901)   |
|103.313469|         5901 > 49988 [SYN,            |TCP: 5901 > 49988 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=65535 Len=0 MSS=1460 WS=8 TSval=0 TSecr=0 SACK_PERM=1
|         |(49988)  <------------------  (5901)   |
|106.281619|         5901 > 49988 [SYN,            |TCP: 5901 > 49988 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=65535 Len=0 MSS=1460 WS=8 TSval=0 TSecr=0 SACK_PERM=1
|         |(49988)  <------------------  (5901)   |
|112.316765|         5901 > 49988 [SYN,            |TCP: 5901 > 49988 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=65535 Len=0 MSS=1460 WS=8 TSval=0 TSecr=0 SACK_PERM=1
|         |(49988)  <------------------  (5901)   |
|124.381196|         POST 192.168.1.2:59           |HTTP: POST 192.168.1.2:5901/ftcontentserver.rcs.mnc.mcc.pub.3gppnetwork.org HTTP/1.1 
|         |(49988)  ------------------>  (5901)   |
|124.381300|         5901 > 49988 [RST]            |TCP: 5901 > 49988 [RST] Seq=1 Win=0 Len=0
|         |(49988)  <------------------  (5901)   |
```

This is the case where it works:

```
|Time     | 192.168.1.3                           | 192.168.1.2                           |
|         |                   | 192.168.1.2       |                   
|117.828732|         42956 > 5901 [SYN]            |                   |TCP: 42956 > 5901 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=14600 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM=1 TSval=2994458 TSecr=0 WS=64
|         |(42956)  ------------------>  (5901)   |                   |
|117.828828|         5901 > 42956 [SYN,            |                   |TCP: 5901 > 42956 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=65535 Len=0 MSS=1460 WS=8 TSval=0 TSecr=0 SACK_PERM=1
|         |(42956)  <------------------  (5901)   |                   |
|117.930471|         42956 > 5901 [ACK]            |                   |TCP: 42956 > 5901 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=14656 Len=0 TSval=2994490 TSecr=0
|         |(42956)  ------------------>  (5901)   |                   |
|117.930932|         [TCP Window Update]           |                   |TCP: [TCP Window Update] 5901 > 42956 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=262800 Len=0 TSval=75822 TSecr=2994490
|         |(42956)  <------------------  (5901)   |                   |
|117.941444|         POST 192.168.1.2:59           |                   |HTTP: POST 192.168.1.2:5901/ftcontentserver.rcs.mnc.mcc.pub.3gppnetwork.org HTTP/1.1 
|         |(42956)  ------------------>  (5901)   |                   |
|117.964006|         HTTP/1.1 204 No Con           |                   |HTTP: HTTP/1.1 204 No Content 
|         |(42956)  <------------------  (5901)   |                   |
```

This is the error I get in the first case: Expert Info (Warn/Protocol): Acknowledgment number: Broken TCP. The acknowledge field is nonzero while the ACK flag is not set

Can someone suggest what could be possibly going wrong?

Here is the wireshark dump

```
No.     Time        Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
      1 0.000000    192.168.1.9           192.168.1.2           TCP      74     49988 > 5901 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=14600 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM=1 TSval=306973 TSecr=0 WS=64

Frame 1: 74 bytes on wire (592 bits), 74 bytes captured (592 bits)
Ethernet II, Src: Lge_4c:96:28 (5c:17:d3:4c:96:28), Dst: IntelCor_d4:8d:40 (00:23:14:d4:8d:40)
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 192.168.1.9 (192.168.1.9), Dst: 192.168.1.2 (192.168.1.2)
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: 49988 (49988), Dst Port: 5901 (5901), Seq: 0, Len: 0

No.     Time        Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
      2 0.000193    192.168.1.2           192.168.1.9           TCP      78     5901 > 49988 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=65535 Len=0 MSS=1460 WS=8 TSval=0 TSecr=0 SACK_PERM=1

Frame 2: 78 bytes on wire (624 bits), 78 bytes captured (624 bits)
Ethernet II, Src: IntelCor_d4:8d:40 (00:23:14:d4:8d:40), Dst: Lge_4c:96:28 (5c:17:d3:4c:96:28)
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 192.168.1.2 (192.168.1.2), Dst: 192.168.1.9 (192.168.1.9)
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: 5901 (5901), Dst Port: 49988 (49988), Seq: 0, Ack: 1, Len: 0

No.     Time        Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
      3 2.968343    192.168.1.2           192.168.1.9           TCP      78     5901 > 49988 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=65535 Len=0 MSS=1460 WS=8 TSval=0 TSecr=0 SACK_PERM=1

Frame 3: 78 bytes on wire (624 bits), 78 bytes captured (624 bits)
Ethernet II, Src: IntelCor_d4:8d:40 (00:23:14:d4:8d:40), Dst: Lge_4c:96:28 (5c:17:d3:4c:96:28)
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 192.168.1.2 (192.168.1.2), Dst: 192.168.1.9 (192.168.1.9)
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: 5901 (5901), Dst Port: 49988 (49988), Seq: 0, Ack: 1, Len: 0

No.     Time        Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
      4 9.003489    192.168.1.2           192.168.1.9           TCP      78     5901 > 49988 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=65535 Len=0 MSS=1460 WS=8 TSval=0 TSecr=0 SACK_PERM=1

Frame 4: 78 bytes on wire (624 bits), 78 bytes captured (624 bits)
Ethernet II, Src: IntelCor_d4:8d:40 (00:23:14:d4:8d:40), Dst: Lge_4c:96:28 (5c:17:d3:4c:96:28)
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 192.168.1.2 (192.168.1.2), Dst: 192.168.1.9 (192.168.1.9)
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: 5901 (5901), Dst Port: 49988 (49988), Seq: 0, Ack: 1, Len: 0

No.     Time        Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
      5 21.067920   192.168.1.9           192.168.1.2           HTTP     148    POST 192.168.1.2:5901/ftcontentserver.rcs.mnc.mcc.pub.3gppnetwork.org HTTP/1.1 

Frame 5: 148 bytes on wire (1184 bits), 148 bytes captured (1184 bits)
Ethernet II, Src: Lge_4c:96:28 (5c:17:d3:4c:96:28), Dst: IntelCor_d4:8d:40 (00:23:14:d4:8d:40)
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 192.168.1.9 (192.168.1.9), Dst: 192.168.1.2 (192.168.1.2)
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: 49988 (49988), Dst Port: 5901 (5901), Seq: 1, Ack: 1, Len: 82
Hypertext Transfer Protocol

No.     Time        Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
      6 21.068024   192.168.1.2           192.168.1.9           TCP      54     5901 > 49988 [RST] Seq=1 Win=0 Len=0

Frame 6: 54 bytes on wire (432 bits), 54 bytes captured (432 bits)
Ethernet II, Src: IntelCor_d4:8d:40 (00:23:14:d4:8d:40), Dst: Lge_4c:96:28 (5c:17:d3:4c:96:28)
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 192.168.1.2 (192.168.1.2), Dst: 192.168.1.9 (192.168.1.9)
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: 5901 (5901), Dst Port: 49988 (49988), Seq: 1, Len: 0
```

Answer (score 1):

For the case, where it is not working, the TCP handshake is not getting completed. The reason for this is the local side is not sending an ACK to the received SYN/ACK. For better readability, I am providing a short/edited variant of the 3-way hand shake:

```
49988 > 5901 [SYN]  |TCP: 49988 > 5901 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=14600 Len=0 MSS=1460
5901 > 49988 [SYN,  |TCP: 5901 > 49988 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=65535 Len=0 MSS=1460
5901 > 49988 [SYN,  |TCP: 5901 > 49988 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=65535 Len=0 MSS=1460
5901 > 49988 [SYN,  |TCP: 5901 > 49988 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=65535 Len=0 MSS=1460
```

For the case, where it fails, the 3-way handshake is complete:

```
42956 > 5901 [SYN]  ||TCP: 42956 > 5901 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=14600 Len=0 MSS=1460
5901 > 42956 [SYN,  ||TCP: 5901 > 42956 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=65535 Len=0 MSS=1460
42956 > 5901 [ACK]  ||TCP: 42956 > 5901 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=14656 Len=0
```

Now, the why part.. Once the connect() is issued, it is the underlying TCP that would send SYN and respond to the SYN-ACK, so I am seeing any bad thing here except that the local stack is taking more time to respond to the SYN-ACK. Also, is the client waiting enough for the connect() to succeed before it sends the request. If connect() does not go through or gets delayed, then it should not send any data on that connection.

Comment: In the case when it does not work, ACK is sent through the POST message, when I expand wireshark logs. But in the case where it works, ACK is sent as a separate message. I dont have access to the client code, but I think they wait for connect to pass, before they send the data. This happens only in some systems

Comment: Well, TCP ACK would always be sent as part of the connect message. The connect() step would return only if the 3-way handshake is done (unless it is non-blocking). So, we are dealing with 2 questions here. First, why is the app sending the POST message before connect() has returned successfully. Next, why is the TCP layer not responding to 3 consequitive SYN-ACK messages from the server. For the second step, if it is a corner case, then there is not much we can do since TCP layer might have a lot of other processing to do that can lead to (rarely) such delay.

Comment: This looks more like a bug in the TCP stack, not the application magically sending data while it is still blocked in connect(), which isn't possible. connect() blocks until it completes, and in any case the stack should ensure that data isn't sent until the connection is ESTABLISHED, i.e. it has sent the the final ACK, which can be piggy-backed on data. There is certainly no need for the program to 'wait'.

Comment: Unless, you have a multi-threaded application, where one application thread sends data without waiting __sufficiently__ for the connect() thread to go through. @user1692342 are you using multiple threads? But, I agree with you that any good TCP stack should not send data if the socket is not connected.

Comment: @ManojPandey I have updated question with wireshark dump. Please check. I am not sure how the client side is implemented

Comment: Even in the multithreading case a TCP stack can't send data until the connection is `ESTABLISHED.` The state diagram in the RFC says so.

Comment: @user1692342 thank you for the additional info. Looking at the wireshark timing info, looks like data is being sent at around 21.0 seconds where the connect happened at around 2-9 seconds. So, by this time the connect() should have returned or at least, it should have sent the last ACK to complete the handshake. It is likely that the underlying stack has a bug.

Comment: At this point, I would suggest, if you can try with another client (let us say a PC) and see if you are running into the same issue in the same work-load scenario.. If you do not see, then this might be a TCP stack issue at the handset device.

Comment: @ManojPandey Thanks for your help. Is there any way I can confirm it is a TCP stack issue at handset device? I will try to check with a PC based client on those systems and see what is the response

Comment: @ManojPandey I have a feeling it may not be a TCP stack issue with respect to handset. Is there a possibility that firewall or some other thing can block off packets?

Comment: At this point, I would say that you would want to take another device and replicate the same conditions. If you dont see an error, then it is an stack issue. I would also do some more research about the device and see if this is a known issue and if possible, file a case with the vendor.